# will_paginate is there a way to set per_page to 'all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5 / Will_Paginate Gem 2.3.15

I have a page section where a user can select how many items per page to display (with an 'all' choice).  I don't like having 'all' in there but each item in the list has a checkbox so that bulk operations can be performed against the listed items (a user couldn't select all items the query would return if the items are broken out into pages).

I haven't found an answer looking around, but is there a way to set the :per_page option to 'all'?   I temporarily just put in a jumbo number (1000000) as a work-around.   Is that the only way to do it?

I thought about just replacing the paginate_by_sql condition with a find_by_sql, but then in the view I'd have to add in logic to not write the "<%= will_paginate @items%>"

```
    if cookies[:items_per_page]
      if cookies[:items_per_page] == 'ALL'
        @items =  Item.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1000000)
      elsif %w(10 20 30 40 50 75 100).any? {|str| cookies[:items_per_page].include? str}
        @items =  Item.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => cookies[:items_per_page].to_i)
      else #cookie doesn't contain a valid choice, default to '10'
        @items =  Item.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
      end
    else #cookie doesn't exist, default to '10'
      @items =  Item.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Item.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => Item.count)
```

Comment: As a side note, doing this puts all the items on one page so if your "page" variable is any number above 1 the offset is going to be higher than the amount of Item records.  Putting everything on one page defeats the purpose of pagination and is probably not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't this count query an over-head?